# In VBA should code that modifies document be avoided in a class module

Tags: vba, excel, ms-word

I am starting to use Classes in VBA and appreciate some of the fantastic information that is already available on SO.

As far as I can tell, what seems to be lacking is an explanation of what the code in a class should or, as I suspect, should NOT do. For example:

Lets say I have a document and wish to insert / modify a table.  In this example I'd like to:

- check if the table exists
- if table does not exist:

  - add the table at a specific location
  - add information to the table (i.e. add rows)
- if table does exist

  - add / delete information to /from the table
  - sort the table according to some criteria

With respect to 'sorting' I imagine that a class module would be well suited to determining the order that information should be put into a table based on some criteria.

**But ideally:**

- Should the class module (or a 2nd class module) be used to check and edit the document?

*OR*

- Would checking and/or editing be best done using a regular module?

Or doesn't it matter?  If there is a preferred way then what are the advantages / disadvantages of each approach?

Comment: A `Document`, in *being* a class is a big hint. There's no reason why your class shouldn't interact with **a** document directly.

Comment: @ThunderFrame - hmmm... well rightly or wrongly, in my projects almost all the code in my ThisDocument is executed in a regular module called docThisDocument because that ~seems to~ makes MS-Word run better... would that be the hint you're referring to?

Comment: You use a class where it makes sense to encapsulate some set of functionality/information in a way that makes your task easier to manage.  Often a class is modelling a "thing" in your workflow.  However, there's no magic there, and it shouldn't make much/any difference to your code's performance.

Comment: No, the hint is that `ThisDocument` *is* a predeclared instance of a class module. You interact with the document *as a class* by using the methods and properties of the class. *Your* class is free to work with `ThisDocument` (or better yet, with *any* document that is handed to your class). There's no reason to use a procedure in a standard module to interact with the document.

Comment: @ThunderFrame - ok, well that's good to know. Everything that I have read about classes suggests that they are a sort of template for an object as opposed to something that should cause modification to the actual document. I suppose principle of single responsibility principle will come in to play and provide guidance somewhere here...

Comment: @TimWilliams - thanks for your thoughts, one of my problems is that I seem to lack the foresight to know what makes sense :(  I have a document with lots of tables, there are different types of tables but for the most part they are all the same (rows of information). One thing that I need to do a lot of is sorting these tables. Sometimes sorting table A means that table B will need to be re-sorted.. and on it goes. I was thinking that, rather than physically sorting tables, I could sort everything in a class then repopulate the tables...

Comment: You can actually do what you described simply by using a generic procedure that does the sorting and then calling it out every time you need to execute the sorting task, not necessarily via *Class*. And yes it doesn't matter actually where you do it be it in a *Class Module* or *Regular Module* as already pointed out by Tim. Work on where you're most comfortable.

Comment: @L42 Yes, I actually have something like that at the moment.  I want to implement some best practice coding techniques and hopefully make the overall project easier to manage.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First off, kudos for entering the wonderful rabbit hole of OOP!

Short answer: **It depends.**

---

(very) long answer:

You'll want to avoid pulling a worksheet [that exists at compile-time] from the `Application.Worksheets` (or `Application.Sheets`) collection, and use that sheet's `CodeName` instead. VBA creates a global-scope object reference for you to use, named after every worksheet's `CodeName`.

That's how this code gets to compile, with `Sheet1` not being declared anywhere:

```
Option Explicit

Sub Test()
    Debug.Print Sheet1.CodeName
End Sub
```

The problem with implementing worksheet-specific functionality anywhere other than in that worksheet's code-behind, using that global-scope "free" object variable, is that the separate module is now *coupled* with that `Sheet1` object.

#### Class module depending on a worksheet. *Any* worksheet.

You want focused, *cohesive* modules - *high cohesion*. And *low coupling*.

By writing worksheet-specific code in another module (be it a standard or a class module), you're creating a *dependency* and increasing *coupling*, which reduces *testability* - consider this code in `Class1`:

```
Public Sub DoSomething()
    With Sheet1
        ' do stuff
    End With
End Sub
```

Now `Class1` can only ever work with `Sheet1`. This would be better:

```
Public Sub DoSomething(ByVal sheet As Worksheet)
    With sheet
        ' do stuff
    End With
End Sub
```

What happened here? *Dependency Injection*. We have a *dependency* on a specific sheet, but instead of coding against that specific object, we tell the world "give me any *worksheet* and I'll do my thing with it". That's at *method* level.

If a class means to work with a single specific worksheet, and exposes multiple methods that do various things with that worksheet, having a `ByVal sheet As Worksheet` parameter on every single method doesn't make much sense.

Instead you'll inject it as a property:

```
Private mSheet As Worksheet

Public Property Get Sheet() As Worksheet
    Set Sheet = mSheet
End Property

Public Property Set Sheet(ByVal value As Worksheet)
    Set mSheet = value
End Property
```

And now all methods of that class can work with `Sheet`... the only problem is that the client code consuming that class now needs to remember to `Set` that `Sheet` property, otherwise errors can be expected. That's bad design IMO.

One solution could be to push the *Dependency Injection Principle* a notch further, and actually *depend on abstractions*; we formalize the interface we want to expose for that class, using *another* class module that will act as the interface - that `IClass1` class doesn't implement anything, it just defines stubs for what's exposed:

```
'@Interface
Option Explicit

Public Property Get Sheet() As Worksheet
End Property

Public Sub DoSomething()
End Sub
```

Our `Class1` class module can now *implement* that interface, and if you've been following this far, hopefully I don't lose you here:

> NOTE: Module and member attributes are not visible in the VBE. They're represented here with their corresponding [Rubberduck](http://rubberduckvba.com) annotations.

```
'@PredeclaredId
'@Exposed
Option Explicit
Implements IClass1

Private mSheet As Worksheet

Public Function Create(ByVal pSheet As Worksheet) As IClass1
    With New Class1
        Set .Sheet = pSheet
        Set Create = .Self
    End With
End Function

Friend Property Get Self() As IClass1
    Set Self = Me
End Property

Private Property Get IClass1_Sheet() As Worksheet
    Set IClass1_Sheet = mSheet
End Property

Private Sub IClass1_DoSomething()
    'implementation goes here
End Sub
```

This `Class1` class module presents *two* interfaces:

- `Class1` members, accessible from the `PredeclaredId` instance:

  - `Create(ByVal pSheet As Worksheet) As IClass1`
  - `Self() As IClass1`
- `IClass1` members, accessible from the `IClass1` interface:

  - `Sheet() As Worksheet`
  - `DoSomething()`

Now the calling code can look like this:

```
Dim foo As IClass1
Set foo = Class1.Create(Sheet1)
Debug.Assert foo.Sheet Is Sheet1
foo.DoSomething
```

Because it's written against the `IClass1` interface, the calling code only "sees" the `Sheet` and `DoSomething` members. Because of the `VB_PredeclaredId` attribute of `Class1`, the `Create` function can be accessed via the `Class1` *default instance*, pretty much exactly like `Sheet1` gets accessed without creating an instance (UserForm classes have that *default instance*, too).

This is the *factory* design pattern: we're using the *default instance* as a *factory* whose role is to create and initialize an implementation of the `IClass1` interface, which `Class1` just so happens to be implementing.

With `Class1` completely decoupled from `Sheet1`, there's absolutely nothing wrong with having `Class1` responsible for everything that needs to happen on whatever worksheet it's initialized with.

*Coupling* is taken care of. *Cohesion* is another problem entirely: if you find `Class1` is growing hair and tentacles and becomes responsible for so many things you don't even know what it was written for anymore, chances are that the *Single Responsibility Principle* is taking a beating, and that the `IClass1` interface has so many unrelated members that the *Interface Segregation Principle* is *also* taking a beating, and the reason for that is probably because the interface wasn't designed with the *Open/Closed Principle* in mind.

---

The above couldn't be implemented with standard modules. Standard modules don't play quite well with OOP, which means tighter coupling and thus lower testability.

---

### TL;DR:

There isn't one single "right" way to design *anything*.

- If your code can deal with being *tightly coupled* with a specific worksheet, **prefer implementing the functionality for that worksheet in that worksheet's code-behind, for better *cohesion***. Still use specialized objects (classes) for specialized tasks: if your worksheet code-behind is responsible for setting up a database connection, sending a parameterized query over the network, retrieving the results and dumping them into the worksheet, then you're *Doing It Wrong™* and now testing that code in isolation, without hitting the database, is impossible.
- If your code is more complex and can't afford tight coupling with a specific worksheet, or if the worksheet doesn't exist at compile-time, **implement the functionality in a class that can work with *any* worksheet**, and have a class that's responsible for the *model* of that runtime-created sheet.

IMO a standard module should only be used to expose entry points (macros, UDFs, Rubberduck test methods, and with `Option Private Module`, some common utility functions), and contain fairly little code that merely initializes objects and their dependencies, and then *it's classes all the way down*.

Comment: Wow - thank you! Yes you did lose me there for a bit - but I think I recovered. I'm actually using MS Word, but appreciate the 'sheet' example. Finally starting to understand coupling and cohesion thanks to your explanation. This has left me with a few questions for clarification... one of which relates to your closing para where you state your opinion that a standard module should only be used to expose entry points (and include macros in a list)... how do you differentiate between a macro and all the rest of the code?

Comment: @SlowLearner to me a "macro" is a parameterless `Public Sub` procedure in a standard module, invoked through some kind of UI - be it a button on a worksheet, a Ribbon button, a shortcut key, or just the host application's *Macros* dialog. I treat those as *entry points*; the functionality they invoke is never implemented directly in such procedures, because then you have a "God module" that knows and does *everything*... and then you can't write unit tests for any of it, because everything is just one big blob of code.

Comment: Do you mean behind the scenes like setting a default as described here: http://www.cpearson.com/excel/DefaultMember.aspx ?

Comment: That's pretty cool :) - Oh just noticed you comment on Macros, somehow missed it earlier, tnx